# Can't upgrade Neo4j 2.2.4 to 2.3.0

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j is failing to upgrade from 2.2.4 to 2.3.0.  I've tried both through the GUI and through Java. I specified `allow_store_upgrade=true` in both environments. Java provides a better error message.  In the stack trace below it says `but file is version ''.]`, but this isn't what the actual error message says on my screen, however the characters would not paste into SO; it looks like this:

[image: neo4j version error]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, C:\Users\pwicks\Documents\Neo4j\tc5
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:43)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:129)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:117)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:185)
    at com.micron.tc.App.main(App.java:53)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@640455b7' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:538)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:109)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:112)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:528)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:109)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:139)
    ... 6 more
    Suppressed: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnexpectedUpgradingStoreVersionException: 'C:\Users\pwicks\Documents\Neo4j\tc5\neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'v0.A.3' but file is version ''.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradeable(UpgradableDatabase.java:96)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:149)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.upgradeStore(NeoStoreDataSource.java:637)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:528)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:528)
    ... 11 more
[CIRCULAR REFERENCE:org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnexpectedUpgradingStoreVersionException: 'C:\Users\pwicks\Documents\Neo4j\tc5\neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'v0.A.3' but file is version ''.]
[CIRCULAR REFERENCE:org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnexpectedUpgradingStoreVersionException: 'C:\Users\pwicks\Documents\Neo4j\tc5\neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'v0.A.3' but file is version ''.]
```

Through the GUI I just get this error:

```
Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@21e4e4a9' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
```

Comment: These steps look all correct. Just to be sure: are you positive that the upgrade parameter became effective, that means the correct properties file is read ? Is 2.2.4 still able to read the database or was it perhaps messed up ?

Comment: If I remove property I get this error: `Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter "allow_store_upgrade=true"`.  I haven't tried rolling back to 2.2.4, but I will.

Comment: was the store cleanly shut down before? are you sure it was a 2.2.4 store?

Comment: @MichaelHunger Yes, or I think so... I just rolled back my project to 2.2.4 and the database opened up without issue.

Comment: In the past we had a similar issue copying the graph database from one so like Windows to Linux. Is this your case?

Comment: @MichaelHunger - I think it wasn't shut down cleanly after all.  I rolled back to 2.2.4 and the database started up without issue.  I shut it down and tried the upgrade to 3.0.0 again and it succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup of the configuration parameters is absolutely correct.

I suggest you verify if your data can be read by the previous version. When this succeeds or after you repaired the database (possibly by restoring a backup) try to update again.